# Coefficient Plot in r for mixed model

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models, sjplot, coefplot

I have fitted a three level model looking at political trust using multiple waves of survey data. Individuals nested in country-waves nested in countries. Now that I have my results, I want to present them in a coefficient plot. I have fitted a coefficient plot using the sjPlot function below. I am only interested in presenting the higher level variables (growth,inflation,unemployment,corruption) as the individual level variables are controls, but the plot puts all the predictors in. I also want to edit the names of certain variables so its clearer. How can I do this? I don't mind suggestions using ggplot or the base r coefplot function.

```
plot_model(fullmodel, transform = NULL, show.values = TRUE)
```

[image: Coefficient Plot 3 level]

Comment: It's very difficult to help you with this unless you provide a minimal reproducible example. Can you perhaps produce a simple example using a built-in data set like `iris` or `mtcars` from which folks here can demonstrate a solution? Thanks

Comment: look at the documentation for plot_model, the `terms` argument seems to do what you want.  also try the `modelsummary` package https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelplot.html